# show magento layer state on catalog listing (not on sidebar)

Tags: php, magento

Is there a way I could load filter layer state on the content area just below the page title[image]

I've tried several ways like including `template/catalog/layer/state.phtml` into `template/catalog/product/list.phtml`, adding below snippet on `<reference name="content">` on catalog.xml

```
<block type="catalog/layer_view" name="catalog.leftnav" after="leftnav" template="catalog/layer/view.phtml"/>
```

nothing works... what should I do?

thanks before :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In page.xml search `<block type="core/text_list" name="content" as="content" translate="label">`:

Paste this code here (drawback: it will load in every content, will be better to find putting it within catalog pages block tag):

```
<block type="catalog/layer_state" name="catalog.layer.state" as="catalog.layer.state" template="catalog/layer/state.phtml"/>
```

Now in`catalog/product/list.phtml` file you can get this by:

```
<?php echo $this->getChildHtml('catalog.layer.state') ?>
```

Answer (score 4):

Here is quick fix: paste this in catalog/product/list.phtml

```
<?php echo $this->getLayout()->createBlock('catalog/layer_state')->setTemplate('catalog/layer/state.phtml')->toHtml(); ?>
```

Comment: This is a good method if all you need to do is access some method that only that block's class has.